# JSX element type "ProcessProvider" does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm learning React Context and I'm using a project that I've build as a test.

After create the context I wrap the App.jsx with the provider but after that it gives me an error: JSX element type "ProcessProvider" does not have any construct or call signatures.

After searching the web I could have not found a solution or not understanding what it does mean since I won't pass any props on the component. The children in here is the other components.

interface.tsx

```
import { RouteChildrenProps } from "react-router";

export default interface Props {
  children?: (
    props: RouteChildrenProps<any>
  ) => React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode;
  processes?: Array<string>;
  setProcesses?: (active: any) => void;
  updating?: boolean;
  setUpdating?: (active: boolean) => void;
  getProcesses?: () => void;
}
```

ProcessContext.tsx

```
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase";
import Props from "../Interface/Api";

const ProcessContext = createContext<Props | undefined>(undefined);

export const ProcessProvider: FC<Props> = ({children}) => {
  const [processes, setProcesses] = useState<Array<any>>([]);
  const [updating, setUpdating] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const getProcesses = async () => {
    const processCollectionRef = collection(db, "processes");
    const data = await getDocs(processCollectionRef);
    setProcesses(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
  };

  return (
    <ProcessContext.Provider
      value={{ processes, setProcesses, updating, setUpdating, getProcesses }}
    >{children}</ProcessContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ProcessContext;
```

App.tsx

```
import Menu from "./Components/Menu";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import CreateProcess from "./Components/CreateProcess";
import DataTable from "./Components/DataTable";
import CourseTable from "./Components/CourseTable";
import {ProcessProvider} from "./context/ProcessContext";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ProcessProvider>
        <Router>
          <Menu />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/novoprocesso" render={(props) => <CreateProcess />} />
            <Route
              path="/processosconcluidos"
              render={(props) => <DataTable />}
            />
            <Route path="/" render={(props) => <CourseTable />} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </ProcessProvider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is giving me an error. How can I solve it?

Comment: The code you provided doesn't seem to have anything wrong in regard to your usage of context. Could you provide a minimal runnable sandbox?

Comment: That's because i edited it. I had a misstype on App.tsx on the import ProcessProvider where i didn't used curly braces. Since it's resolved and was a misstype i will delete this post.